# Efficient way to check if an element is in a comma separated string?

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I have a blacklist like `"12,3,4,5,6,789"`,

I tried

```
set = {}
for element in string.gmatch("12,3,4,5,6,789", "([^"..", ".."]+)") do
    set[element] = true
end 

if set[...] then
    ...
end
```

to check if an element is in the blacklist.

My program will process more than one (element,blacklist) pair per request, for each pair i build a set and only use it once.

I thought it's inefficient and tried to use `string.match`, but the pattern in lua is not standard RegEx and I failed to write a pattern that can match element at start/mid/end of the blacklist correctly at the same time.

- Will `string.match` be more efficient than build a set?
- How to write a proper pattern?
- Is there any way more efficient?

Comment: `element = "789"; if ("12,3,4,5,6,789"):find("%f[%d]"..element.."%f[%D]") then print("Access Denied") end`

Comment: Cool, I'd like to accept this. @Egor Skriptunoff

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching is easiest when there are no corner cases:

```
string.match(","..blacklist..",",
             ","..element..",")
```

Answer (score 0):

short solution:

```
local blacklist = "31,415,9265,3589,7932,3846,2643,383,279"
local item = "383"
blacklist= ","..blacklist..","
if blacklist:find(","..item..",") then
   print("found in the blacklist")
end
```

ps:this is my understanding of the original task

Comment: Try item equal to 1... Make sure your solution works for a list such as `31,415,9265,3589,7932,3846,2643,383,279` with items such as 3, 41, 15, 92, 65, etc.

Comment: Why do you think `find` is faster than `match`?

Comment: Isn't plain `find` faster than `match`?